# Can Jenkins run some code or it is only scheduling external programs?

Tags: jenkins

I'm new to Jenkins and I heard it is really good for continues integration.
My flow is not complicated: I need to get a list from SQL by some query, parse it line by line, send each line to some virtual machines (which will run this line and create some file as result), and then analyze the results.

Where in Jenkins can I program my code?

Is Jenkins' purpose is only to schedule external programs one by one and not to run the code in Jenkins itself?

Is there a way to write code in jenkins that is not a bunch of CMD commands?

Answer (score 0):

you can do the following ( syntaxic pipline ) :
- stage 1 : execute command over ssh (jenkins plugin) to execute sql query 
- stage 2 : send each line to dedicated VM with Ansible playbook
- stage 3 : analyze depend on the tech you are using there are plenty of jenkins plugin to connect to monitoring and analyzing tools like grafana or zabbix .. that can ease the process

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are asking for is scripted pipeline: https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/

This allows you to write Groovy code to execute on the Jenkins master.  You can do almost anything you want from there, just like any programming language.